# Advice on Views navigation using Caliburn.Micro MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm new on Caliburn Micro and want some advice on which path to take to devolop my app interface and navigation between views. 
My idea is to have a MainWindow which will contain a menu of buttons, each one related with a specific view. Each view will be stored in a separated WPF UserControl. The mainWindow will also contain a TabControl bound to an ObservableCollection of tabs on viewmodel. Everytime a button on menu is clicked, I want to add a new tab with a ContentPresenter inside that will dynamically load a view and its corresponding viewmodel.

**So my questions:**

> 1) Should I use a Screen Collection here?
>
> 2) Should the UserControl implement Screen interface?
>
> 3) How do I tell MainWindow ViewModel which view to load on the new added tab maintaining viewmodels decoupled?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

**UPDATE**

After a lot of reading and some help of the community I managed to resolve this. This is the resultant AppViewModel:

```
class AppViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public void OpenTab(Type TipoVista)
    {
        bool bFound = false;
        Screen myScreen = (Screen)Activator.CreateInstance(TipoVista as Type);
        myScreen.DisplayName = myScreen.ToString();
        foreach(Screen miItem in Items)
        {
            if (miItem.ToString() == myScreen.ToString())
            {
                bFound = true;
                ActivateItem(miItem);
            }                
        }
        if (!bFound) ActivateItem(myScreen);        
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> myMenu { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<LinksItem> myDirectLinks { get; set; }

    public ICommand OpenTabCommand
    {
        get
        {                
            return new RelayCommand(param => this.OpenTab((Type) param), null);
        }
    }       

    public AppViewModel()
    {
        OpenTab(typeof(ClientsViewModel));            
        MenuModel menu = new MenuModel();
        myMenu = menu.getMenu();
        myDirectLinks = menu.getLinks();
    }        

    public void CloseTab(Screen param)
    {            
        DeactivateItem(param, true);
    }    
}
```

I have to keep the ICommand from OpenTabCommand because the name convention of Caliburn.micro doesn't seems to work inside DataTemplate. Hope it could help someone else. Thanks to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done something very similar using `Caliburn.Micro`, and based it on the `SimpleMDI` example included with the examples, with a few tweaks to fit my needs.

Much like in the example, I had a main `ShellViewModel`:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
}
```

with a corresponding `ShellView` containing a `TabControl` - `<TabControl x:Name="Items">`, binding it to the `Items` property of the the `Conductor`.

In this particular case, I also had a `ContextMenu` on my `ShellView`, bound (using the `Caliburn.Micro` conventions), to a series of commands which instantiated and `Activated` various other `ViewModels` (usually with a corresponding `UserControl`, using the `ActivateItem` method on the `Conductor`.

```
public class YourViewModel: Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    // ...

    public void OpenItemBrowser()
    {
        // Create your new ViewModel instance here, or obtain existing instance.
        // ActivateItem(instance)
    }
}
```

In that case, I didn't require the `ViewModels` to be created with any particular dependency, or from any other locations in the program.

At other times, when I've needed to trigger `ViewModel` from elsewhere in the application, I've used the `Caliburn.Micro` `EventAggregator` to publish custom events (e.g. `OpenNewBrowser`), which can be handled by classes implementing the corresponding interface (e.g. `IHandle<OpenNewBrowser>`), so your main `ViewModel` could have a simple `Handle` method responsible for opening the required `View`:

```
public class YourViewModel: Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IHandle<OpenNewBrowser>
{
    // ...

    public void Handle(OpenNewBrowser myEvent)
    {
        // Create your new ViewModel instance here, or obtain existing instance.
        // ActivateItem(instance)
    }
}
```

[This section](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) of the documentation will probably be useful, especially the Simple MDI section.

Additional code I mentioned in the comments:

I sometimes use a generic method along these lines ensure that if I have an existing instance of a screen of a particular type, switch to it, or create a new instance if not.

```
public void ActivateOrOpen<T>() where T : Screen
{
    var currentItem = this.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(T));

    if (currentItem != null)
    {
        ActivateItem(currentItem);
    }
    else
    {
        ActivateItem(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
public void OpenBrowser()
{
    this.ActivateOrOpen<BrowserViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i need! I have been done some test myself and also find that could adapt the SimpleMDI simple to my needs. The only thing i did different is how to open new views (Using ActivateItem) because i have a menu where i wanted to link every menu option to specific view, so i use "Screen myScreen = (Screen)Activator.CreateInstance(ViewType as Type);" passing the ViewType as a reference to the viewmodel class type. If you see my update i post my AppViewModel. Thank you again!

Comment: That makes sense =D I sometimes use a generic method to control the screens that I only want one instance of, I'll post it in an edit, rather than trying to wedge it in here.