# Call A Method From A Control That Is Not In The DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a button in a UserControl that I want to call a method in another class (which happens to be my main window's view model).

```
<ToggleButton cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ToggleWatch]">
```

The user control's DataContext is tied to a DataTemplate. This makes everything beautiful, unless I run into cases like this where implementing the ToggleWatch method in the DataTemplate class doesn't make much sense, since the DataTemplate should only contain data.

Is the best way to get around this is by setting the DataContext of this control to the MainWindowViewModel? That workaround fails when I want to bind a value from the DataTemplate to the same button, since the DataContext modification will then make it look for the value in the MainWindowViewModel.

In case I've over complicated the question, I will summarise. I have a UserControl whose DataContext is a seperate DataTemplate. I want to call a method from a button when it is clicked, but I want the method seperated from the DataTemplate. I want the method in a completely different class. What is the best way to solve this?

Here is how I'm setting the DataTemplate:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:DeviceCleanerBox/>
                ...
```

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the DataContext of your `UserControl` to a `DataTemplate`?

Comment: Actually no, I'm not. I am however explicitly setting the `DataTemplate` of the `UserControl` using XAML. In case it makes a difference, I'll add how I'm setting the `DataTemplate` to my question.

Comment: Ah, so does the `DataContext` get set to whichever `ViewModel` is backing the `ItemsControl`?

Comment: Yes. I think that applies to types of controls.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would solve your problem based on my understanding, but the `EventAggregator` and associated `Handle` interfaces may help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203379/advice-on-views-navigation-using-caliburn-micro-mvvm-wpf/23254345#23254345

Comment: I just want to say thanks for the help. I can't look into that solution now, but when I do have the time I will reply back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserControl must exist as child of your MainWindow and if i am right you must have set DataContext of MainWindow to be MainWindowViewModel.

So, what you can do is **declare ICommand in MainWindowViewModel and bind to button's Command using RelativeSource** to search for window's DataContext:

```
<ToggleButton Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandName,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                        AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: That is not 100% ideal since I must implement a Command just for this, but it really seems to be the only way. Thanks for the help!